# How to prevent parent click event when the user clicks on his child element? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, z-index

I have a `<div>` with a `ng-click` but this `<div>` have a **child element** with also a `ng-click` directive.
The problem is that the **click event on the child element** trigger **also** the **click event of the** **parent element**.

How can I prevent the parent click event when I click on his child?

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qu86oxzc/2/) to illustrate my situation.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
<div id="parent" ng-click="parentClick()">
    <div id="child" ng-click="childClick()"></div>

    <p ng-bind="elem"></p>
</div>

<div><p style="text-align:center" ng-bind="childElem"></p></div>
</body>

<script>
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.parentClick = function() {
        $scope.elem = 'Parent';
    }

    var i = 1;
    $scope.childClick = function() {
        $scope.elem = 'Child';
        $scope.childElem = 'Child event triggered x' + i;
        i++;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Either turn event bubbling off for the child handler or check what was clicked in the handler using event.target / this / yourFrameworksImplementationOfEventTarget

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use the event.stopPropagation() method.
see:  http://jsfiddle.net/qu86oxzc/3/

```
<div id="child" ng-click="childClick($event)"></div>

$scope.childClick = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now but thank you that is exactly what I want.
I didn't think about it cause I never pass the element generally.

But is there another way to perform this without stopPropagation ?

Comment: you 'could' do something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/33281294/1782659 but I think this is really ugly. Stopping the event from bubling higher up is the right thing to do (imo)

you can also look at the target of the event (if $event.target === childElement)

Answer (score 7):

Use `event.stopPropagation` to stop the `event` from bubbling up the DOM tree from child event handler.

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lkr4L0zb/)

```js
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.parentClick = function() {

    $scope.elem = 'Parent';
  }

  var i = 1;
  $scope.childClick = function(e) {
    $scope.elem = 'Child';
    $scope.childElem = 'Child event triggered x' + i;
    i++;

    e.stopPropagation(); // Stop event from bubbling up
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: #00acee;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#parent:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#child {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#child:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#parent p {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
  <div id="parent" ng-click="parentClick()">
    <div id="child" ng-click="childClick($event)"></div>
    <!--                                 ^^^^^^^     -->
    <p ng-bind="elem"></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style="text-align:center" ng-bind="childElem"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

also you can use this as it use do the same.

```
<div id="child" ng-click="childClick();$event.stopPropagation();"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if Pieter Willaert's answer is much more beautiful i updated your fiddle with a simple boolean check:

http://jsfiddle.net/qu86oxzc/6/

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.boolean = false;
    $scope.parentClick = function () {
        if (!$scope.boolean) $scope.elem = 'Parent';
        $scope.toggleBoolean();
    }

    var i = 1;
    $scope.childClick = function () {
        $scope.boolean = true;
        $scope.elem = 'Child';
        $scope.childElem = 'Child event triggered x' + i;
        i++;
    }

    $scope.toggleBoolean = function () {
        $scope.boolean = !$scope.boolean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `$event.stopPropagation();`. write it after the child function. It working like a **preventdefault**.

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
<div id="parent" ng-click="parentClick()">
    <div id="child" ng-click="childClick();$event.stopPropagation();"></div>

    <p ng-bind="elem"></p>
</div>

<div><p style="text-align:center" ng-bind="childElem"></p></div>
</body>
```